# how to search for a sub string within a string in QBasic

Tags: qbasic

I am creating a simple chat programme in QBasic that will answer questions based on some specific key words present in the user input.therefore I need a way to search for a sub string (I.e. A specific word)within a string.
So, please help me.

Comment: you should post the code you have already ...

Comment: See http://www.garybeene.com/qbasic/qb-tutor-strings.htm and look for instr.

Comment: This link describes INSTR in QB64: http://www.qb64.net/wiki/index.php/INSTR

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To find out if a string contains a certain (sub-)string, you can do this:

```
text$ = "nonsense !"
IF INSTR( text$, "sense" ) >= 1 THEN
  PRINT "This text makes sense !"
END IF
```

And no, I was not able to test this, as a no longer have QBasic on my PC ;-) 
According to the link from the comment above >= 1 is ok

Comment: I works and even there is no need to use >=1 until that word is repeated more than once

Comment: @NilakshSingh that is good news. So now you can accept one of the answers ;-)

Answer (score 4):

I think INSTR is usually used as follows:

```
sent$ = "This is a sentence"

PRINT INSTR(1, sent$, "is")
PRINT INSTR(4, sent$, "is")
PRINT INSTR(1, sent$, "word")
```

the first PRINT command will print a '3' since the first location of "is" within the sentence is at position 3. (The 'is' in 'This')

the second PRINT command starts searching at position 4 (the 's' in 'This'), and so finds the "is" at position 6. So it will print '6'.

the third PRINT command will print a '0' since there is no instance of "word" in the sentence.

Answer (score 3):

Counts the occurrences of a substring within a string.

```
T$ = "text to be searched and to be displayed"
S$ = "to"
l = 1
DO
    x = INSTR(l, T$, S$)
    IF x THEN
        n = n + 1
        l = x + LEN(S$)
    ELSE
        EXIT DO
    END IF
LOOP
PRINT "text '"; S$; "' matches"; n; "times."
```

Comment: Counts the occurrences of a substring within a string.

Comment: This might be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: I would remove the ELSE part and end the loop with `LOOP WHILE x`.

Comment: True. I could also replace it with LOOP UNTIL x = 0